# Cómo puedo eliminar carpetas vacías con un archivo .bat

Tags: cmd, windows10, .bat

```
del /q/s "C:\Users\Hrgdd\AppData\Local\Temp\*.*"
```

Ese es el comando que he utilizado para eliminar los archivos, como pueden ver en la carpeta de archivos temporales. Siempre que lo ejecuto no da problemas para eliminar los archivos, pero siempre quedan carpetas vacías sin eliminar, ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar robocopy y poner el mismo directorio como segundo argumento, de igual manera te recomiendo cambiar la ruta por la variable %TEMP%

```
del /q /s %TEMP%
ROBOCOPY %TEMP% %TEMP% /S /MOVE
```

Bueno, aquí te dejo otro método para eliminar todo de tu %TEMP%

```
@echo off
cd /D %temp%
for /d %%D in (*) do rd /s /q "%%D"
del /f /q *
```

Answer (score 0):

Con el comando RD puedes eliminar carpetas vacías y con subcarpetas o archivos, o eliminar todo un Árbol.

```
@echo off
rd /Q  C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Temp
```

Comment: ¿Y no habría riesgo de eliminar todo el %TEMP%? ¿Funcionará? porque el %TEMP% tiene archivos que no puedes eliminar por que están en uso o son necesarios para el sistema

Comment: Me sale este error al ejecutarlo :s `El proceso no tiene acceso al archivo porque está siendo utilizado por otro proceso.`

Comment: no es solo un ejemplo, el quieres borrar la carpeta Windows tiene una herramienta, se llama `Elminar archivos Temporales` puedes borrar el contenido de la carpeta pero no la carpeta, y tienes que tener todo cerrado o no te dejara, si quieres crear un bat para que al darle click te elimine todo automáticamente, seria el codigo asi: ```@echo off 
del /Q C:\Users\%username%\\AppData\Local\Temp\*.* ```